# how to call CDHtmlDialog::GetDHtmlDocument after dom is loaded?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, mfc, atl

I call `CDhtmlDialog::GetDHtmlDocument() in CDhtmlDialog.OnInitDialog()`, but I found the return values is NULL.

However if I put `GetDHtmlDocument()` in a button clicking handler, the returned `IHtmlDocument` is valid. So I think maybe the DOM is not loaded when I call `CDhtmlDialog::GetDHtmlDocument()`?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853904/1764118).

Comment: @AnonymousCoward Thanks, it works! could you post the answer, so I can accept your answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GetDHtmlDocument() in MFC programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853607/how-to-use-getdhtmldocument-in-mfc-programming)